# How to upload a picture from CameraRoll to a server

Tags: php, upload, camera, air

I don't know why but I can't figure out how to upload a picture from the CameraRoll on my AIR app to my server.

Here's my code :

```
function initCamera(evt:Event):void{    
  cameraRoll.addEventListener( MediaEvent.SELECT, imageSelected );
 cameraRoll.browseForImage();
}

function imageSelected( event:MediaEvent ):void{

     //PREVIEW OF THE IMAGE
     var mp:MediaPromise = event.data;
    mediaPath.text = mp.file.name + "\n" + mp.file.url;
    Imgloader.source = mp.file.url;
     uploadImage();

     function uploadImage():void{

            feedbackText.text = "uploadImage";
            var req = new URLRequest();
            req.url = ( stage.loaderInfo.parameters.f )? stage.loaderInfo.parameters.f : 'http://www.****-**/***/uploadImg.php';
            mp.file.upload(req);
            mp.file.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progress_func );

}
}
```

Any idea what's wrong with the code ?

The function "upload" is triggered but nothing is uploading... (and progress_func is not triggered)